# Accessing array elment in JSON object is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, undefined

I am relatively new to javascript and very new to JSON and got the job of changing an internal website so it meets our new company needs.
I am trying to access a JSON object with an array in it. This actually works pretty for most of the objects, except the array. Everytime I try to access the elements in the array I get undefined or NaN.

When I do

```
alert(JSON.stringify(object.data.average[0]));
```

I get the following output

```
[{"test_count2":"360","succeeded":"185"}]
```

so I know the objects I am trying to access are there, but when I do

```
alert(JSON.stringify(object.data.average[0].succeeded))
```

or

```
alert(JSON.stringify(object.data.average[0]['succeeded']))
```

I always get just

```
undefined
```

Am I doing something entirely wrong here? 
As I sad, I am a newby, so please be patient with me ;)

thanks in advance!

Comment: better to paste your whole (or atleast `object.data.average`)  JSON data , as it seems to me that there is an array inside another array ( `object.data.average[0][0]` ?)

Comment: "average":
{
 "0":
 [
  {
   "test_count":"360",
   "succeeded":"185"
  }
 ]
 ,
 "test_count":"192",
 "failed":"7",
 "succeeded":"185",
 "ratio":"0.5978",
 "id":"41",
 "overall_status":"1"
},
Still I dont get why there is an array inside the array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's yet another array you would have to do this

```
object.data.average[0][0]['succeeded'];
```

Comment: No problems, happy hacking!

Answer (score 1):

Try with `JSON.stringify(object.data.average[0][0].succeeded)`.
It seems that `object.data.average[0]` returns an array with a single element in it.
Also, you can use `console.log(object.data)`, instead of `alert`. It's way easier to see a tree representation of an object in the console on a modern web-browser, instead of alerting string values like in the old days.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have forgotten that you have another object inside your array. Try,

```
alert(JSON.stringify(object.data.average[0][0].succeeded))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to access the succeeded value from the "stringified json" , you will need to convert the string  '[{"test_count2":"360","succeeded":"185"}]' which is now a plain string back to an json object.

Steps are: 
    var str = '[{"test_count2":"360","succeeded":"185"}]';
    var obj = JSON.parse(str); //This function reverses what JSON.stringify does to a json 
    alert(obj.succeeded); //Output: 185

Hope i was clear :)